# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ix\omega}(\frac{\sin(\omega)}{\omega})^2 d\omega$ using convolution theorem.

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I have study Fourier transformation and found this exercise: Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ix\omega}(\frac{\sin(\omega)}{\omega})^2 d\omega$ using convolution theorem. I have notice that integral looks like inverse Fourier transformation, where $(\frac{\sin(\omega)}{\omega})^2$ is some function's Fourier transformation. Is there any hint how I can use convolution theorem to solve this?

Comment: Start with $g=\chi_{[-1,1]}$ and find the Fourier transform. Should be $\sin(\omega)/\omega$, maybe with a few constants thrown in. Figure out how to modify so you get $\hat g(\omega)=\sin(\omega)/\omega$ exactly. Now think about $g*g$...

Answer (score 2):

Let the Fourier Transform of $f(\omega)$ be given by

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega$$

We have the Fourier Transform pairs

$$\begin{align}
f(\omega) &\leftrightarrow F(x)\\\\
f^2(\omega) &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi}F(x)*F(x)\tag1\\\\
\frac{\sin(\omega)}{\omega}&\leftrightarrow \pi\,\text{rect}(x/2)\tag2\\\\
\frac{\sin^2(\omega)}{\omega^2}&\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\pi\,\text{rect}(x/2)\right)*\left(\pi\,\text{rect}(x/2)\right)=\pi\, \text{tri}(x/2)\tag3
\end{align}$$

where $\text{rect}(t)$ and $\text{tri}(t)$ are the [Rectangle Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) and [Triangle Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function), respectively.

---

**NOTES:**

The pair in $(1)$ expresses the result of the Convolution Theorem.

To arrive at $(1)$, we use the result $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\,dx=\pi \text{sgn}(a)$.  Proceeding we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega)}{\omega}e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega&=\frac1{2i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i\omega(x+1)}-e^{i\omega(x-1)}}{\omega}\,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 \text{sgn}(x+1)-\frac\pi2 \text{sgn}(x-1)\\\\
&=\pi\,\text{rect}(x/2)
\end{align}$$

And finally, using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\sin(\omega)}{\omega}\right)^2 e^{i\omega x}\,d\omega&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\pi\,\text{rect}((x-x')/2)\right)\left(\pi\,\text{rect}(x'/2)\right)\,dx'\\\\
&=\pi\,\text{tri}(x/2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: @psi Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I  really want to give you the best answer I can.